# Why RandomShuffleQueue in TensorFlow keep dequeueing the same values?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to test the RandomShuffleQueue in TensorFlow. The queue first enqueue three times a variable with value increased by 1.0, so the queue should be like [1., 2., 3.].Then dequeue two times. I expected that the output would randomly be selected from 1, 2, 3. But it always outputs 3, which is confusing.

The test code is showed below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

i = tf.Variable(0.0)
one = tf.constant(1.0)
ass_op = tf.assign(i, tf.add(i, one))

q = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(10, min_after_dequeue=1, dtypes=tf.float32)
enq_op = q.enqueue([ass_op])
deq_op = q.dequeue()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run([q.size(), ass_op, enq_op]))
    print(sess.run([q.size(), ass_op, enq_op]))
    print(sess.run([q.size(), ass_op, enq_op]))
    print(sess.run([q.size(), deq_op]))
    print(sess.run([q.size(), deq_op]))
```

and the output is:

```
[0, 1.0, None]
[1, 2.0, None]
[2, 3.0, None]
[3, 3.0]
[2, 3.0]
```

UPDATE:
I found that this issue only appears in Mac OS, while testing in Linux and Windows works fine as I expected. Moreover, FIFOQueue has the same problem. A more detailed test code is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

i = tf.Variable(0.0)
ass_op = tf.assign(i, i+1.0)

q = tf.FIFOQueue(20, dtypes=tf.float32)
enq_op = q.enqueue([ass_op])
deq_op = q.dequeue()

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# code 1
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(enq_op)  
for i in range(10):
    print(sess.run(deq_op))

# code 2
for i in range(10):
    sess.run(enq_op)
    print(sess.run(deq_op))
```

while code 2 works as expected, code 1 goes wrong in ONLY Mac OS.

Comment: your code is perfectly fine and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine and it works fine. It might have been the case that when you ran the code you got the same output a few times. Which is possible.

I ran your code and made some changes to it and below code was working fine for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf

i = tf.Variable(0.0)
one = tf.constant(1.0)
ass_op = tf.assign(i, tf.add(i, one))

q = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(10, min_after_dequeue=1, dtypes=tf.float32)
enq_op = q.enqueue([ass_op])
deq_op = q.dequeue()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(3):
        print(sess.run([q.size(), ass_op, enq_op]))
    for i in range(2):
        print(sess.run([q.size(), deq_op]))
```

output:

```
[0, 1.0, None]
[1, 2.0, None]
[2, 3.0, None]
[3, 1.0]
[2, 3.0]
--
[0, 1.0, None]
[1, 2.0, None]
[2, 3.0, None]
[3, 3.0]
[2, 2.0]
```

Comment: Actually, I found that this issue only appears in Mac OS. When I test the code with both linux and windows, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are adding the same elements to your queue (problem with you assign part).

Here is a random queue which randomly extracts elements:

```
import tensorflow as tf

q = tf.RandomShuffleQueue(10, min_after_dequeue=1, dtypes=tf.float32)
init = q.enqueue_many(([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7.],))
res  = q.dequeue()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in xrange(5):
        print sess.run(res)
```